# Bitmap's height and width changes irrespective of image height and width Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to get the Bitmap's height and width. I set the screen resolution as 3264x2448. When I get the Bitmap's height and width it shows as 153x204. I use the following code,

```
Bundle bun = imageReturnedIntent.getExtras();
Bitmap selectedImage = (Bitmap) bun.get("data");
int height = selectedImage.getHeight();
int width()= selectedImage.getWidth();
```

Is there anyway to get the Bitmap's height and width(same as device screen resolution) in Android. Anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to scale it to the size of the screen?  If so, use createScaledBitmap in the bitmap class to create a new bitmap of that size.

Comment: createScaledBitmap reduces the quality of image and makes the photo blurred.

Comment: That's what happens when you scale a bitmap.  If you want it to be screen width and height without those effects, you need to use an image that was created with the right size by the artist.